# Suggestions for a batch audio converter?

Tags: audio, file-conversion

Any suggestions for a good, free audio converter for Mac? 
I used to use Max.app but it has long become abandonware and is now super buggy and crashy. I just need something I drop a couple (or 20 thousand) Apple Lossless files into and let it crank away making me some AAC compressed files or some MP3 or whatever.

Comment: Handbrake works a treat on many files ...

Comment: [XLD](http://tmkk.undo.jp/xld/index_e.html) though I still usually use Max, even if it is abandonware. Never tried throwing more than a couple or three albums at a time at it, though.

Comment: XLD is pretty good. Using from long time.

Comment: @SolarMike does handbrake do audio files?

Answer (score 1):

[FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/) and a simple bash script will get the job done.  FFMPEG is the same set of libraries that are included with products like Handbrake.

The basic syntax is very simple:

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile outputfile
```

If you wanted to convert a FLAC to MP4, you would simply enter

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.FLAC to outputfile.MP4
```

To convert a number of files a simple bash script like the one below will convert

```
for file in /foo/bar/*.mp3
do
    fullfilename=$(basename "${file}")
    filename="${fullfilename%.*}"
    ffmpeg -i "$file" "/foo/bar/converted/$filename.mp4"
done
```

This basic script parses through a directory, takes the original filename, then removes the extension so a new extension can be added during output.