# Convert AMR to MP3 in Terminal?

Tags: audio, file-conversion, mp3

Is there an integrated system utility that will allow one to rapidly convert AMR files to MP3 in the shell on macOS?

Comment: There isn't an internal one, but you can use [ffmpeg](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/325688/suggestions-for-a-batch-audio-converter/325714#325714)

Comment: have you tried this command?  "ffmpeg -i audio1.amr -ar 22050 audio1.mp3". Works on linux but don't know about Mac.

Comment: @jmh seems like it should work, but I need to figure out why the right encoder is not available yet. Got this error: "Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:0. Default encoder for format amr (codec amr_nb) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually.
Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:0"

Comment: @jmh's answer works for me on macOS