# Is there any way to convert a bunch of .ogg files in a folder to .mp3 using ffmpeg?

Tags: macos, bash, automation, mp3

Is there any way to convert a whole heap of .ogg files in about 30 folders in a folder containing those folders to .mp3 files and put them in another folder using the command `ffmpeg`? The previous methods I have tried all led to the same error: "*.ogg no such file or directory"

If possible could you please tell me how? I cant find anything relating to this specific question.

Edit: I've tried to edit the command and now it's giving me this error:
(this goes for all of the files in the folder)

```
/Users/Macbook/Downloads/Minecraft+Sound+Pack+1.13/step/wood6.ogg~/Downloads/Minecraft\ Sounds/step/wood6.mp3: No such file or directory
```

I used this:

```
$ for file in ~/Downloads/Minecraft+Sound+Pack+1.13/step/*.ogg 
> do
>     fullfilename=$(basename "${file}")
>     filename="${fullfilename%.*}"
>     ffmpeg -i "$file""~/Downloads/Minecraft\ Sounds/step/$filename.mp3"
> done
```

I think it's trying to link both directories together.

Comment: The above code did not work. If ffmpeg is supposed to read in folders inside the directory, then something is wrong with ffmpeg. I have tried "ffmpeg -i "{}" "{.}.mp3" ::: *.ogg", "for i in *.ogg; do ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.*}.mp3"; done" and the above code.

Comment: @user10829240 Did you try to convert one file separately to check if ffmpeg works on your system? `ffmpeg -i file_name.ogg file_name.mp3`

Comment: If you have a code snippet already, please add it directly to the question and explain where it fails.

Comment: Ffmpeg is not supposed to read inside of directories; all it does is take  input of some format and output it as another , that’s it. Reading “inside”a directory is dependent on how you code it.  Without seeing your code, it’s impossible to say why it’s failing.

Comment: ffmpeg does work on my system. I used it the other day to convert a 1h 30m video from .flv to .mp4 because I couldn't open the file on my system. It worked perfectly without any error.

Comment: The error message is telling you it can't find the file or directory.  As for your `ffmpeg` command, your not formatting it correctly.  Can you attempt just one conversion and see how that goes?

Comment: The conversion worked fine on a .ogg file in the directory.

Comment: The sample misses a space character between the input and the output name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't it astonishing how such small problems create a bunch of solutions :-)

Download the ZIP file, then run

```
unzip "Minecraft Sound Pack 1.13.zip" -d mc
cd mc/
find . -type f -iname '*.ogg' -execdir sh -c \
    'ffmpeg -v 8 -i "$1" "${1%.*}.mp3" && rm -- "$1" && echo "$1"' sh {} \;
```

This will replace all `.ogg` files with the `.mp3` version, deleting the `.ogg` file in the process. You still have the original data in the ZIP file if needed.

- `-type f` ensures that only files get matched (otherwise a directory named `foo.ogg` would be passed to `ffmpeg` for processing as well)
- The `-execdir` option runs the following command within the directory the file was found (so we don't need to worry about stripping path names)
- Because `-execdir` can only run *one* command we start a new shell and pass the set of commands via `-c`
- `ffmpeg -v 8 -i "$1" "${1%.*}.mp3" && rm -- "$1" && echo "$1"`is the actual command getting executed, with the name of the file to be converted as `$1`
- `sh {}` are the parameters passed to the shell script as `$0` and `$1` respectively. `sh` is only required for syntactical reasons (you could put any word there, some people use `_` for instance), `{}` gets replaced by the currently found file
- `\;` terminates the `-execdir` part (actually `;` does, but it needs to get escaped from bash who would interpret it as a command terminator otherwise)

PS: If you want to see the details from `ffmpeg` remove the `-v 8` part.

Comment: Thank You! This solved my problem. I kindly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

As an example, I have a bunch of `.ogg` files in my `Downloads` directory, so... to batch convert a bunch of `.ogg` files in a given directory to `.mp3` files in the same directory, I did the following in **Terminal**:

```
cd Downloads
for f in *.ogg; do ffmpeg -i "$f" "${f%.*}.mp3"; done
```

This created an `.mp3` file for each `.ogg` file I have in my **Downloads** directory.

So, using your directory path, do the following:

```
cd ~/Downloads/Minecraft+Sound+Pack+1.13/step
for f in *.ogg; do ffmpeg -i "$f" "${f%.*}.mp3"; done
```

---

That said and considering your dealing with a sound file pack you downloaded from the Internet, Minecraft+Sound+Pack+1.13.zip, which contains 131 *directories*, some nested 3 or more deep, and *1406* `.ogg` files, of which some of the *filenames* are the same, I would handle the situation with the following conditions in mind.

1. I downloaded the `Minecraft+Sound+Pack+1.13.zip` file from the Internet.
2. Expanded the zip archive by double-clicking on it in my Downloads folder in Finder. Note that this is because I do not let the Browser unzip downloaded archive files. This also retains a copy of the zip archive in case I still need it afterwards.

With that done, I used the following *example bash script* to convert each `.ogg` file within the *hierarchal folder structure* to an `.mp3` file at the same location. Then delete the `.ogg` files, as I still have the original zip archive.

```
#!/bin/bash

    # s="/Path/To/Source/Files"

s="$HOME/Downloads/Minecraft+Sound+Pack+1.13"

for d in $(find "$s" -type f -iname '*.ogg' | sed -E 's|/[^/]+$||' | sort -u); do
    cd "$d"
    for f in *.ogg; do
        ffmpeg -i "$f" "${f%.*}.mp3"
        rm "$f"
    done
done
```

- You only need to change the *value* of `s="..."` as or if needed and as a general rule I like to use `$HOME` in place of `~`.

Note that this is just how I choose to deal with the situation in the moment and there are many different ways that a script could be written.  This however I believe achieves the end goal of having the *hierarchal folder structure* of the 131 *directories* intact with the 1406 converted `.mp3` *files*.

By the way... On my old MacBook Pro, (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013) 2.8 GHz Intel Core i7, it took just under 9 minutes to process the 1406 `.ogg` *files*.

Comment: The shell script cracks over at Unix&Linux would probably have a field day with the parsing of `find` results (even though it will not break for the specific problem) :-)

Comment: @nohillside, It's usually parsing the output of `ls` that typically gets shot-down and parsing `find` is the recommendation over it. I'll say that for another one-off type particular scenario I'd use again what I posted because it was tested several times and worked without issue and I just didn't want to take the time to formulate the command line needed in conjunction with `-execdir` and `find` and go through the testing as I found it easier to test the direction I went. However, there's no doubt in my mind that your answer is the better way to go between them, just not the only way!

Comment: I know that you know what you are doing here :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using the base logic in the post, [Suggestions for a batch audio converter?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/325714/119271), we just have to do a simple nested `for/do` loop to iterate through each of your directories.  Assuming the best case scenario that the directories are only one child directory deep and the files are pretty clean (nothing other than `.ogg`) this script will automatically convert the files for you.

```
#!/bin/bash

base_dir="~/Downloads"
newbase_dir="~/Downloads/New Sounds"

cd "$base_dir"
for dir in */
do
  for file in *
  do
    fullfilename=$(basename "${file}")
    newfilename="${fullfilename%.*}"
    echo
    echo "Converting ${file} to $newfilename.mp3
    ffmpeg -i "$file" "${newbasedir}/${dir}/${filename}.mp3"
  done
done
```

#### Script Logic

Basically, it will iterate through each file in each directory processing it through `ffmpeg` converting from `.ogg` to `.mp3` keeping the directory structure of the original.  There are two variables you need to set:

- `base_dir` - the starting point of where the files are located
- `new_base_dir` - the directory where you want all the files to end up.

If you don't want the directory structure kept, just rewrite the `ffmpeg` line to read:

```
ffmpeg -i "$file" "${newbase_dir}/${filename}.mp3"
```

Comment: @user3439894 - I made assumptions that I detailed in the first paragraph....  It's easily fixed with adding the `ogg` extension. I could have added error checking for both the directory and file, but this is just for the script logic.

Comment: Considering the OP is dealing with a sound file pack downloaded from the Internet, Minecraft+Sound+Pack+1.13.zip, which contains 131 directories, some nested 3 or more deep, and 1406 .ogg files... your script as presently coded fails for multiple reasons.